# C# Check for !null and string.Empty on a JSON response throws FormatException

Tags: c#, json, isnullorempty

I wrote a simple API call within a method expecting a JSON response... Nothing spectacular:

```
// [API call...]

dynamic responseString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
item.category               = responseString.category;
item.shortDescription       = responseString.shortDescription;
item.countryOfManufacture   = responseString.manufacturerCountry ?? "DE";
```

Sometimes there are not all required parameters from the API available... So I tried to check for *`is null`* and *`is string.Empty`* and raise a dialog where the user can enter the missing values...

But this:

```
            if (responseString.weight == null ||responseString.weight == string.Empty )
            {
                DialogArgs args = new DialogArgs();
                args.Add("Gewicht");
                OnMissingValue?.Invoke(args);
                item.weight = args.Get<float>("Gewicht");
            }
            else
            {
                item.weight = Convert.ToSingle(responseString.weight) / 1000;
            }
```

or

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseString.weight))
```

throws a *FormatException*.
If I check either *`is null`* or *`is string.Empty`* it works like a charm. I know the differnence between ref and value types and thought maybe there is a Problem... However, I like to know why it behaves like this...

Thanks in advance... and sorry for my english...

Markus

Comment: That if-statement does **not** throw a `FormatException`. The code inside the if-then block might but please narrow it down.

Comment: I guess 'Convert.ToSingle' throws the exception.

Comment: No, it's definitly not the code inside and it is a 'FormatException' wothout inner Exceptions... The Stacktrace isn't very usefull...

Comment: the exception is thrown by the if statement... the code inside doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I get it... The `dynamic` descriptor is the reason. You have to cast it to a *string* like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)responseString.weight))
```

...thanks for your effort

Markus